How to apply a fill color to a text object in Illustrator?
I try to recolor text object. The color PANTONE 185 C is present in the swatches and if object type is CompoundPathItem then it works. But when a text object selected then it lost a color (that is, it turns into an object without fill).
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var swatches = doc.swatches;

if (doc.selection.length > 0) {
    var targetItem = doc.selection[0];

    if (targetItem.typename == "PathItem" || targetItem.typename == "CompoundPathItem") {
        var colorFound = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < swatches.length; i++) {
            if (swatches[i].name == "PANTONE 185 C") {
                alert("PANTONE 185 C");
                targetItem.fillColor = swatches[i].color;
                colorFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!colorFound) {
            alert("PANTONE 185 C not found in Swatches");
        }
    } else {
      
      alert("apply fill color");
      var textRange = targetItem.textRange;
      applyFillColor(textRange, swatches[i].color);
      
    }
    
} else {
    alert("select an object");
}

function applyFillColor(textRange, color) {
    for (var i = 0; i < textRange.characters.length; i++) {
        textRange.characters[i].fillColor = color;
    }
}


So have you tried the suggested solutions? Were there some problems? It's hard to guess without a feedback since you didn't even provide your test AI-file.

As for the error, in the line applyFillColor(textRange, swatches[i].color); the variable i is undefined at this point. It's rather weird that Illustrator doesn't get an error in this line and silently returns 'undefined' (or sets the value to zero and returns swatches[0]?). it's need to change more than a couple lines to fix the problem. I've provided the possible solutions bellow.

Downvote since there is no feedback on the suggested solutions for several days.

I'd propose to use a recursion and try/catch like this:
function applyFillColor(item, color) {
    try { item.fillColor = color } catch(e) {}
    try { for (var i=0; i<item.length; i++) applyFillColor(item[i], color) } catch(e) {}

    try { applyFillColor(item.pathItems, color)         } catch(e) {}
    try { applyFillColor(item.compoundPathItems, color) } catch(e) {}
    try { applyFillColor(item.textRanges, color)        } catch(e) {}
    try { applyFillColor(item.textFrames, color)        } catch(e) {}
    try { applyFillColor(item.groupItems, color)        } catch(e) {}
}

function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    var pantone = 'PANTONE 185 C';
    try { var color = doc.swatches.getByName(pantone).color }
    catch(e) { alert('Not found the color: ' + pantone); return }

    var sel = doc.selection;
    if (sel.length == 0) { alert ('Select a text or object(s)'); return }

    applyFillColor(sel, color);
}

main();

Here is a speed optimized variant of the function applyFillColor():
function applyFillColor(item, color) {

    if (item instanceof PathItem || item instanceof TextRange) {
        item.fillColor = color;
        return;
    }

    if (item instanceof CompoundPathItem) {
        item.pathItems[0].fillColor = color;
        return;
    }

    if (item instanceof TextFrame) {
        for (var i=0; i<item.textRanges.length; i++) applyFillColor(item.textRanges[i], color);
        return;
    }

    if (item instanceof Array) {
        for (var i=0; i<item.length; i++) applyFillColor(item[i], color);
        return;
    }

    if (item instanceof GroupItem) {
        for (var i=0; i<item.pathItems.length; i++)         applyFillColor(item.pathItems[i], color);
        for (var i=0; i<item.compoundPathItems.length; i++) applyFillColor(item.compoundPathItems[i], color);
        for (var i=0; i<item.textFrames.length; i++)        applyFillColor(item.textFrames[i], color);
        for (var i=0; i<item.groupItems.length; i++)        applyFillColor(item.groupItems[i], color);
        return;
    }

    // etc
    try { item.fillColor = color } catch(e) {}
}

Note. Sometimes the item instanceof ... gets an error (Illustrator's API is pretty buggy). You can change it with item.typename == '...'. Especially for the internal Extendscript objects: PathItem, TextRange, CompoundPathItem, TextFrame.

it works slowly and is clearly not the answer

The obvious error in your script is in the line: applyFillColor(textRange, swatches[i].color);. The swatches[i].color is undefined in this place. But there are other problems as well. So I decided to provide a universal solution. It can be speed up for particular tasks: if you always select only one object, if your object is never a group, etc. It's up to you to simplify the code. I just added fixed version of your script.

Sorry, your script contains too much errors. (Looks a bit like it was based on AI). It's surprise if it works at all. Nevertheless, if you insist to use it, here is the fixed (to a degree) version:
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var swatches = doc.swatches;

if (doc.selection.length > 0) {
    var targetItem = doc.selection[0];

    var colorFound = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < swatches.length; i++) {
        if (swatches[i].name == "PANTONE 185 C") {
            alert("PANTONE 185 C");
            var color = swatches[i].color;
            colorFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!colorFound) {
        alert("PANTONE 185 C not found in Swatches");
    }

    else {
        if (targetItem.typename == "PathItem") {
            targetItem.fillColor = color
        } else {
            if (targetItem.typename == "CompoundPathItem") {
                targetItem.pathItems[0].fillColor = color;
            } else {
                alert("apply fill color");
                var textRange = targetItem.textRange;
                applyFillColor(textRange, color);
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    alert("select an object");
}

function applyFillColor(textRange, color) {
    for (var i = 0; i < textRange.characters.length; i++) {
        textRange.characters[i].fillColor = color;
    }
}

It can't handle groups, several selected objects, can't recolor selected text (text range, not a text frame), and it looks pretty awfull. But it works somehow.
